# Multiple "Smarty" based errors after fixing an template

Tags: php, html, smarty, prestashop-1.6

This is a rather misterious case. My "Prestashop" based website was working flawlessly, until this error popped up without editing anything for days:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught --> Smarty Compiler: Syntax error in template    
"/themes/default-bootstrap/product-list.tpl" on line 213 "{/foreach}"
unknown tag "foreachclose" <-- thrown in
/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatecompilerbase.php on line 213
```

Content of the template file:

```
{*
* 2007-2015 PrestaShop
*
* NOTICE OF LICENSE
*
* This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
* that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
* It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
* http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
* If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
* obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
* to license@prestashop.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
*
* DISCLAIMER
*
* Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade PrestaShop to newer
* versions in the future. If you wish to customize PrestaShop for your
* needs please refer to http://www.prestashop.com for more information.
*
*  @author PrestaShop SA <contact@prestashop.com>
*  @copyright  2007-2015 PrestaShop SA
*  @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
*  International Registered Trademark & Property of PrestaShop SA
*}
{if isset($products) && $products}
    {*define number of products per line in other page for desktop*}
    {if $page_name !='index' && $page_name !='product'}
        {assign var='nbItemsPerLine' value=3}
        {assign var='nbItemsPerLineTablet' value=2}
        {assign var='nbItemsPerLineMobile' value=3}
    {else}
        {assign var='nbItemsPerLine' value=4}
        {assign var='nbItemsPerLineTablet' value=3}
        {assign var='nbItemsPerLineMobile' value=2}
    {/if}
    {*define numbers of product per line in other page for tablet*}
    {assign var='nbLi' value=$products|@count}
    {math equation="nbLi/nbItemsPerLine" nbLi=$nbLi nbItemsPerLine=$nbItemsPerLine assign=nbLines}
    {math equation="nbLi/nbItemsPerLineTablet" nbLi=$nbLi nbItemsPerLineTablet=$nbItemsPerLineTablet assign=nbLinesTablet}
        {math equation="(total%perLine)" total=$smarty.foreach.products.total perLine=$nbItemsPerLine assign=totModulo}
        {math equation="(total%perLineT)" total=$smarty.foreach.products.total perLineT=$nbItemsPerLineTablet assign=totModuloTablet}
        {math equation="(total%perLineT)" total=$smarty.foreach.products.total perLineT=$nbItemsPerLineMobile assign=totModuloMobile}
   <!-- Products list -->
    <ul{if isset($id) && $id} id="{$id}"{/if} class="product_list grid row{if isset($class) && $class} {$class}{/if}">
    {foreach from=$products item=product name=products}
        {if $totModulo == 0}{assign var='totModulo' value=$nbItemsPerLine}{/if}
        {if $totModuloTablet == 0}{assign var='totModuloTablet' value=$nbItemsPerLineTablet}{/if}
        {if $totModuloMobile == 0}{assign var='totModuloMobile' value=$nbItemsPerLineMobile}{/if}
        <li class="ajax_block_product{if $page_name == 'index' || $page_name == 'product'} col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3{else} col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4{/if}{if $smarty.foreach.products.iteration%$nbItemsPerLine == 0} last-in-line{elseif $smarty.foreach.products.iteration%$nbItemsPerLine == 1} first-in-line{/if}{if $smarty.foreach.products.iteration > ($smarty.foreach.products.total - $totModulo)} last-line{/if}{if $smarty.foreach.products.iteration%$nbItemsPerLineTablet == 0} last-item-of-tablet-line{elseif $smarty.foreach.products.iteration%$nbItemsPerLineTablet == 1} first-item-of-tablet-line{/if}{if $smarty.foreach.products.iteration%$nbItemsPerLineMobile == 0} last-item-of-mobile-line{elseif $smarty.foreach.products.iteration%$nbItemsPerLineMobile == 1} first-item-of-mobile-line{/if}{if $smarty.foreach.products.iteration > ($smarty.foreach.products.total - $totModuloMobile)} last-mobile-line{/if}">
            <div class="product-container" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Product">
                <div class="left-block">
                    <div class="product-image-container">
                        <a class="product_img_link" href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$product.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" itemprop="url">
                            <img class="replace-2x img-responsive" src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_image, 'home_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" alt="{if !empty($product.legend)}{$product.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{else}{$product.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}" title="{if !empty($product.legend)}{$product.legend|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{else}{$product.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{/if}" {if isset($homeSize)} width="{$homeSize.width}" height="{$homeSize.height}"{/if} itemprop="image" />
                        </a>
                        {if isset($quick_view) && $quick_view}
                            <div class="quick-view-wrapper-mobile">
                            <a class="quick-view-mobile" href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" rel="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                                <i class="icon-eye-open"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <a class="quick-view" href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" rel="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                            <span>{l s='Quick view'}</span>
                        </a>
                        {/if}
                        {if (!$PS_CATALOG_MODE && ((isset($product.show_price) && $product.show_price) || (isset($product.available_for_order) && $product.available_for_order)))}
                            <div class="content_price" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/Offer">
                                {if isset($product.show_price) && $product.show_price && !isset($restricted_country_mode)}
                                    <span itemprop="price" class="price product-price">
                                        {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="before_price"}
                                        {if !$priceDisplay}{convertPrice price=$product.price}{else}{convertPrice price=$product.price_tax_exc}{/if}
                                    </span>
                                    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="{$currency->iso_code}" />
                                    {if $product.price_without_reduction > 0 && isset($product.specific_prices) && $product.specific_prices && isset($product.specific_prices.reduction) && $product.specific_prices.reduction > 0}
                                        {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="old_price"}
                                        <span class="old-price product-price">
                                            {displayWtPrice p=$product.price_without_reduction}
                                        </span>
                                        {if $product.specific_prices.reduction_type == 'percentage'}
                                            <span class="price-percent-reduction">-{$product.specific_prices.reduction * 100}%</span>
                                        {/if}
                                    {/if}
                                    {if $PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT && isset($product.available_for_order) && $product.available_for_order && !isset($restricted_country_mode)}
                                        <span class="unvisible">
                                            {if ($product.allow_oosp || $product.quantity > 0)}
                                                    <link itemprop="availability" href="https://schema.org/InStock" />{if $product.quantity <= 0}{if $product.allow_oosp}{if isset($product.available_later) && $product.available_later}{$product.available_later}{else}{l s='In Stock'}{/if}{/if}{else}{if isset($product.available_now) && $product.available_now}{$product.available_now}{else}{l s='In Stock'}{/if}{/if}
                                            {elseif (isset($product.quantity_all_versions) && $product.quantity_all_versions > 0)}
                                                    <link itemprop="availability" href="https://schema.org/LimitedAvailability" />{l s='Product available with different options'}

                                            {else}
                                                    <link itemprop="availability" href="https://schema.org/OutOfStock" />{l s='Out of stock'}
                                            {/if}
                                        </span>
                                    {/if}
                                    {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="price"}
                                    {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="unit_price"}
                                {/if}
                            </div>
                        {/if}
                        {if isset($product.new) && $product.new == 1}
                            <a class="new-box" href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                                <span class="new-label">{l s='New'}</span>
                            </a>
                        {/if}
                        {if isset($product.on_sale) && $product.on_sale && isset($product.show_price) && $product.show_price && !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
                            <a class="sale-box" href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                                <span class="sale-label">{l s='Sale!'}</span>
                            </a>
                        {/if}
                    </div>
                    {if isset($product.is_virtual) && !$product.is_virtual}{hook h="displayProductDeliveryTime" product=$product}{/if}
                    {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="weight"}
                </div>
                <div class="right-block">
                    <h5 itemprop="name">
                        {if isset($product.pack_quantity) && $product.pack_quantity}{$product.pack_quantity|intval|cat:' x '}{/if}
                        <a class="product-name" href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$product.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" itemprop="url" >
                            {$product.name|truncate:45:'...'|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
                        </a>
                    </h5>
                    {capture name='displayProductListReviews'}{hook h='displayProductListReviews' product=$product}{/capture}
                    {if $smarty.capture.displayProductListReviews}
                        <div class="hook-reviews">
                        {hook h='displayProductListReviews' product=$product}
                        </div>
                    {/if}
                    <p class="product-desc" itemprop="description">
                        {$product.description_short|strip_tags:'UTF-8'|truncate:360:'...'}
                    </p>
                    {if (!$PS_CATALOG_MODE AND ((isset($product.show_price) && $product.show_price) || (isset($product.available_for_order) && $product.available_for_order)))}
                    <div class="content_price">
                        {if isset($product.show_price) && $product.show_price && !isset($restricted_country_mode)}
                            {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type='before_price'}
                            <span class="price product-price">
                                {if !$priceDisplay}{convertPrice price=$product.price}{else}{convertPrice price=$product.price_tax_exc}{/if}
                            </span>
                            {if $product.price_without_reduction > 0 && isset($product.specific_prices) && $product.specific_prices && isset($product.specific_prices.reduction) && $product.specific_prices.reduction > 0}
                                {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="old_price"}
                                <span class="old-price product-price">
                                    {displayWtPrice p=$product.price_without_reduction}
                                </span>
                                {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" id_product=$product.id_product type="old_price"}
                                {if $product.specific_prices.reduction_type == 'percentage'}
                                    <span class="price-percent-reduction">-{$product.specific_prices.reduction * 100}%</span>
                                {/if}
                            {/if}
                            {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="price"}
                            {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="unit_price"}
                            {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type='after_price'}
                        {/if}
                    </div>
                    {/if}
                    <div class="button-container">
                        {if ($product.id_product_attribute == 0 || (isset($add_prod_display) && ($add_prod_display == 1))) && $product.available_for_order && !isset($restricted_country_mode) && $product.customizable != 2 && !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
                            {if (!isset($product.customization_required) || !$product.customization_required) && ($product.allow_oosp || $product.quantity > 0)}
                                {capture}add=1&amp;id_product={$product.id_product|intval}{if isset($product.id_product_attribute) && $product.id_product_attribute}&amp;ipa={$product.id_product_attribute|intval}{/if}{if isset($static_token)}&amp;token={$static_token}{/if}{/capture}
                                <a class="button ajax_add_to_cart_button btn btn-default" href="{$link->getPageLink('cart', true, NULL, $smarty.capture.default, false)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" rel="nofollow" title="{l s='Add to cart'}" data-id-product-attribute="{$product.id_product_attribute|intval}" data-id-product="{$product.id_product|intval}" data-minimal_quantity="{if isset($product.product_attribute_minimal_quantity) && $product.product_attribute_minimal_quantity >= 1}{$product.product_attribute_minimal_quantity|intval}{else}{$product.minimal_quantity|intval}{/if}">
                                    <span>{l s='Add to cart'}</span>
                                </a>
                            {else}
                                <span class="button ajax_add_to_cart_button btn btn-default disabled">
                                    <span>{l s='Add to cart'}</span>
                                </span>
                            {/if}
                        {/if}
                        <a class="button lnk_view btn btn-default" href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='View'}">
                            <span>{if (isset($product.customization_required) && $product.customization_required)}{l s='Customize'}{else}{l s='More'}{/if}</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    {if isset($product.color_list)}
                        <div class="color-list-container">{$product.color_list}</div>
                    {/if}
                    <div class="product-flags">
                        {if (!$PS_CATALOG_MODE AND ((isset($product.show_price) && $product.show_price) || (isset($product.available_for_order) && $product.available_for_order)))}
                            {if isset($product.online_only) && $product.online_only}
                                <span class="online_only">{l s='Online only'}</span>
                            {/if}
                        {/if}
                        {if isset($product.on_sale) && $product.on_sale && isset($product.show_price) && $product.show_price && !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
                            {elseif isset($product.reduction) && $product.reduction && isset($product.show_price) && $product.show_price && !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
                                <span class="discount">{l s='Reduced price!'}</span>
                            {/if}
                    </div>
                    {if (!$PS_CATALOG_MODE && $PS_STOCK_MANAGEMENT && ((isset($product.show_price) && $product.show_price) || (isset($product.available_for_order) && $product.available_for_order)))}
                        {if isset($product.available_for_order) && $product.available_for_order && !isset($restricted_country_mode)}
                            <span class="availability">
                                {if ($product.allow_oosp || $product.quantity > 0)}
                                    <span class="{if $product.quantity <= 0 && isset($product.allow_oosp) && !$product.allow_oosp} label-danger{elseif $product.quantity <= 0} label-warning{else} label-success{/if}">
                                        {if $product.quantity <= 0}{if $product.allow_oosp}{if isset($product.available_later) && $product.available_later}{$product.available_later}{else}{l s='In Stock'}{/if}{else}{l s='Out of stock'}{/if}{else}{if isset($product.available_now) && $product.available_now}{$product.available_now}{else}{l s='In Stock'}{/if}{/if}
                                    </span>
                                {elseif (isset($product.quantity_all_versions) && $product.quantity_all_versions > 0)}
                                    <span class="label-warning">
                                        {l s='Product available with different options'}
                                    </span>
                                {else}
                                    <span class="label-danger">
                                        {l s='Out of stock'}
                                    </span>
                                {/if}
                            </span>
                        {/if}
                    {/if}
                </div>
                {if $page_name != 'index'}
                    <div class="functional-buttons clearfix">
                        {hook h='displayProductListFunctionalButtons' product=$product}
                        {if isset($comparator_max_item) && $comparator_max_item}
                            <div class="compare">
                                <a class="add_to_compare" href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" data-id-product="{$product.id_product}">{l s='Add to Compare'}</a>
                            </div>
                        {/if}
                    </div>
                {/if}
            </div><!-- .product-container> -->
        </li>
    {/foreach}
    </ul>
{addJsDefL name=min_item}{l s='Please select at least one product' js=1}{/addJsDefL}
{addJsDefL name=max_item}{l s='You cannot add more than %d product(s) to the product comparison' sprintf=$comparator_max_item js=1}{/addJsDefL}
{addJsDef comparator_max_item=$comparator_max_item}
{addJsDef comparedProductsIds=$compared_products}
{/if}
```

Someone pointed out that 3 lines of the mentioned file were missing. After I added them I got this array of errors popping up on my website but it was at least loading again:

```
Warning: math: function call total not allowed in 
/tools/smarty/plugins/function.math.php on line 53

Warning: math: function call total not allowed in 
/tools/smarty/plugins/function.math.php on line 53

Warning: math: function call total not allowed in 
/tools/smarty/plugins/function.math.php on line 53

Notice: Undefined index: totModulo in 
/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d 
code on line 87

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in   
/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d
code on line 87

Notice: Undefined index: totModuloTablet in 
/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d 
code on line 88

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in 
/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d 
code on line 88

Notice: Undefined index: totModuloMobile in 
/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d 
code on line 89

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
/tools/smarty/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php(157) : eval()'d 
code on line 89

Warning: math: function call total not allowed in 
/tools/smarty/plugins/function.math.php on line 53

Warning: math: function call total not allowed in 
/tools/smarty/plugins/function.math.php on line 53

Warning: math: function call total not allowed in
/tools/smarty/plugins/function.math.php on line 53
```

I now had the idea of installing Prestashop again and copying the smarty plugin into the directory again to simply hope that it will fix the problem. It seems quite corrupted or something like that since I absolutely didn't touch mentioned php files. I also disabled all non-prestashop modules to verify that it wasn't caused by them.

Comment: about which Smarty plugin you talk? Based on warnings and notices, looks like somewhere in templates  you call `total` function, use undefined array index `totModulo` etc. Show this code, looks like problem is there

Answer (score 0):

Those three lines:

```
{math equation="(total%perLine)" total=$smarty.foreach.products.total perLine=$nbItemsPerLine assign=totModulo}
{math equation="(total%perLineT)" total=$smarty.foreach.products.total perLineT=$nbItemsPerLineTablet assign=totModuloTablet}
{math equation="(total%perLineT)" total=$smarty.foreach.products.total perLineT=$nbItemsPerLineMobile assign=totModuloMobile}
```

Should be placed after the `{foreach}` in your template:

```
{math equation="nbLi/nbItemsPerLine" nbLi=$nbLi nbItemsPerLine=$nbItemsPerLine assign=nbLines}
{math equation="nbLi/nbItemsPerLineTablet" nbLi=$nbLi nbItemsPerLineTablet=$nbItemsPerLineTablet assign=nbLinesTablet}
<!-- Products list -->
<ul{if isset($id) && $id} id="{$id}"{/if} class="product_list grid row{if isset($class) && $class} {$class}{/if}">
{foreach from=$products item=product name=products}
    {math equation="(total%perLine)" total=$smarty.foreach.products.total perLine=$nbItemsPerLine assign=totModulo}
    {math equation="(total%perLineT)" total=$smarty.foreach.products.total perLineT=$nbItemsPerLineTablet assign=totModuloTablet}
    {math equation="(total%perLineT)" total=$smarty.foreach.products.total perLineT=$nbItemsPerLineMobile assign=totModuloMobile}
```

You placed them before the `{foreach}` while calling `total=$smarty.foreach.products.total` so `total` is undefined and `math` throws an error.